# Histogram in seaborn/matplotlib that shows all binned data indexes in x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, seaborn

I need to make a histogram of all values in the given lists. I've used a distplot from seaborn, but one of the axis doesn't show the indexes from 0 to the last element in the list, instead it shows some form of distribution.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
print(sns.__version__)

sns.set_context(font_scale=1.5)

data = [1.1992198, 1.2429917, 0.7515156, 1.7279389, -0.16715668, 0.94465995, 0.5149495, 0.94465995, 0.94465995, 3.8740897, 7.453125, 7.453125, 1.0201894, 1.444468, 0.06495813, 0.18581325, -0.69003785, 3.1213043, 0.24899049, -0.5395518, 2.6421795, 2.238052, -0.42627642, 0.689369, 1.0177083, 0.0021173293, 0.19708821, -0.6978323, -0.27355388, -1.0527502, -1.2287112, -0.73426425, -1.5779951, -1.4275085, -0.72636086, 0.49798694, 0.5233074, -0.8736689, -1.5343369, 0.83868057, 0.14993721, -1.5746347, -1.1844425, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328, 1.9799328]

data2 = [0.34094468, -1.8498722, -0.35345584, -1.0018779, 0.18884292, -2.6028345, 0.39934048, -0.119069986, -0.20210052, -0.2972668, -0.8640028, -0.6174464, 0.096682094, -1.9147822, -0.7738649, 0.6141649, 0.86409974, -0.5216787, -0.78182876, 0.22742827, -0.840597, -0.97359276, -0.018100848, -0.5059276, -1.7152423, -0.07815174, 0.18345535, -0.76344514, -0.39645284, 0.18889628, -0.5543669, -0.18788649, -0.13553666, 0.1379985, 0.65224963, 0.5777133, -0.9204392, -0.91472155, -0.58848035, -1.6883624, -0.58383256, 0.25340325, -0.09143271, 0.50240713, 0.8944117, 0.07218201, 1.1128205, 1.3817745, -0.09530114, 0.56783175, -0.12059356, 0.43868077, -0.2728266, 0.61756617, -0.51779836, -0.39096248, -0.635239, -0.635239, -0.5384383, -0.635239, -0.6920986, -0.9351034, -0.9254051, -0.842712, -1.1218141]

data3 = [0.72135484, -0.706092, 0.36165744, 0.40211153, 0.14495818, 0.9395333, 1.450367, 0.32213485, 0.52471924, 3.3083296, 6.7051606, 6.1889296, -0.210258, -0.09990394, -0.85894525, -0.36614275, -1.5075212, 1.8715478, 0.29819223, -1.0022302, 2.108101, 1.8913394, -0.24430388, 0.059003413, -0.39443398, -0.0057572527, 0.5327027, -1.4999104, -0.60988855, -0.95330614, -1.9033353, -0.93208313, -1.7135317, -1.2041125, 0.007865965, 1.0655571, -0.42969102, -1.9678588, -2.165072, -1.1763439, -0.4736237, -0.8522189, -1.073197, 2.3406122, 2.8758054, 1.9956598, 3.3263054, 3.0907226, 1.8059512, 2.533312, 2.1851382, 2.1604633, 1.7256155, 2.912341, 2.0519354, 2.0519354, 2.0519354, 2.0519354, 2.0519354, 2.0519354, 2.0519354, 2.0519354, 2.0519354, 2.0519354, 2.0519354]

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

# bins don't seem to do anything here
sns.distplot(data, norm_hist=0, hist=False, kde_kws={"shade":True, "bw": 0.05}, bins=100, color="b", label="attn")
sns.distplot(data2, norm_hist=0, hist=False, kde_kws={"shade":True, "bw": 0.05}, bins=100, color="g", label="attn_rel_pos")
pls = sns.distplot(data3, norm_hist=0, hist=False, kde_kws={"shade":True, "bw": 0.05}, bins=100, color="r", label="attn_comb")
plt.legend()


pls.axes.set_title("Title")
pls.set(xlabel='Show indexes from 0 to last here', ylabel='My Weight')
```

The outcome is the following:

[image]

I need to show how the weights from the lists are distributed from 0 index of the list up until the last one (all three lists have the same length). I could potentially bin them since the lists are about 60 elements long, but I also can't find any bin parameter that actually works here.

Here is a photoshopped version of what I would need (but I would also need the data to be presented properly, and not as some form of dense distribution):
[image]

At this point I also don't care if it's seaborn or not, if it is easier to do in matplotlib then I am fine with that solution too. Thank you so much!

EDIT: an example where values are always higher than 0 and using bars instead of histogram, would it be possible to show the values as a continuous line:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
# print(sns.__version__)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
# Not showing the data lists here

def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / np.exp(x).sum(axis=0)

# attn
data = [1.2227119, 2.3106432, 0.3175479, 2.6548655, 0.87468535, -2.5941365, -2.8492305, -2.5941365, -2.5941365, 0.78577393, -3.1803715, -3.1803715, -2.527419, -0.32336473, -0.23149578, 0.1958992, -1.1464257, -1.3171446, -0.82610035, -0.6265811, -0.04922826, 1.268781, -0.63436747, 1.6067829, -0.12655944, 0.30039954, -0.16766489, -2.2401857, -0.036131226, -0.22972624, -0.041365635, 0.6901127, -1.3901691, -0.87032473, 0.13755159, 0.013177752, 1.343483, 0.17142272, -0.08306693, 0.9223409, -0.43641013, -1.2699138, -1.0307136, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937, -0.91284937]

# attn_pos
data2 = [ 0.41763785, -2.3683536, -0.10784631, -0.18569931, 0.20513327, -2.017535, -0.13072428, -1.423852, -0.037444096, -0.29240212, -0.33224604, -0.8710863, -0.2023627, -0.72792727, -0.15152885, 0.20426698, 0.9366691, -0.04617013, 0.03217609, -1.2339046, -0.54832625, -1.0488682, -0.13601255, 0.46882343, -1.1635672, -0.98546046, -0.5023038, -1.7461116, -0.38710907, -0.75636834, -0.077942476, -1.5930176, -0.8428734, 0.36083415, -0.235654, 0.27319083, 0.2481483, -0.8994429, 0.51432747, 0.3907901, -1.0105598, -0.3258296, -0.53897303, 1.3885188, -0.8589748, -0.25751373, 0.9007931, 0.64612645, -0.9111746, -0.5629407, 0.5113405, -0.5913975, 0.8435228, -0.0041873083, 1.2919891, 0.49669626, 0.96742135, 0.96742135, 0.9375946, 0.96742135, 0.62772936, 0.2486542, 0.59175867, 0.13839966, 0.33540285]

# combined
data3 = [1.2788991, 1.8618634, -0.39062586, 2.4721837, 3.1994174, -2.539834, -1.7466183, -2.7143257, -2.5147946, 2.0141108, -3.282056, -3.381072, -3.5476263, -0.7556571, -0.9092123, 0.39682359, -0.7735753, -0.5908251, -1.0364372, -1.0283178, -0.7909626, 1.2081728, -0.96530867, 2.3020573, 0.84674144, 0.7156407, 0.1626791, -1.6639395, 0.27049372, 0.5723161, -0.89840394, 1.5462611, -2.1371794, -1.70861, 0.30733263, 0.22821441, 0.7041679, -0.36799663, 0.27130017, 0.98303056, -1.142178, -2.035885, -1.7442997, -0.49790236, -1.6333843, -0.09258777, -1.971946, -1.0179313, -1.1023216, -0.7061392, -1.0784137, -1.8746437, -0.015198052, -0.9757373, -0.43436813, -0.43436813, -0.43436813, -0.43436813, -0.43436813, -0.43436813, -0.43436813, -0.43436813, -0.43436813, -0.43436813, -0.43436813]

softmax_flag = True

if softmax_flag:
    plt.bar(range(len(data)), softmax(data), color='b', alpha=0.3, label ='attn') #, hatch="/")
    plt.bar(range(len(data2)), softmax(data2), color='g', alpha = 0.3, label ='attn_rel_pos') #, hatch="o")
    plt.bar(range(len(data3)), softmax(data3), color='r',alpha = 0.3, label ='attn_comb') #, hatch="\\")
    plt.plot(range(len(data)), softmax(data),'bx', alpha = 0.5)
    plt.plot(range(len(data2)), softmax(data2),'go', alpha = 0.5, ms = 4)
    plt.plot(range(len(data3)), softmax(data3),'r+', alpha = 0.5)
else:
    plt.bar(range(len(data)), data, color='b', alpha=0.3, label ='attn') #, hatch="/")
    plt.bar(range(len(data2)), data2, color='g', alpha = 0.3, label ='attn_rel_pos') #, hatch="o")
    plt.bar(range(len(data3)), data3, color='r',alpha = 0.3, label ='attn_comb') #, hatch="\\")
    plt.plot(range(len(data)), data,'bx', alpha = 0.5)
    plt.plot(range(len(data2)), data2,'go', alpha = 0.5, ms = 4)
    plt.plot(range(len(data3)), data3,'r+', alpha = 0.5)

plt.title("Head 3")
plt.xlabel("Word Position in the Sentence")
plt.ylabel("Attention Weight")

# plt.grid()
plt.legend(fontsize=16)

plt.savefig('head_3_in_32_softmax.png', dpi=350)

# plt.close(fig)
```

Image: [image]

Comment: Do you want a histogram plot? Have you tried `plt.hist()`? Can you provide a desired output plot?

Comment: You could try to set the distplot- kwarg kde=False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you want some sort of discrete peaks at each value of index as a kind of histogram plot. But from your question I guess the following is what you want:

```
plt.bar(range(len(data)), data, color='b', alpha=0.3, label ='attn')
plt.bar(range(len(data2)), data2, color='g', alpha = 0.3, label ='attn_rel_pos')
plt.bar(range(len(data3)), data3, color='r',alpha = 0.3, label ='attn_comb')
```

**Output**

[image]

In case you want to somehow differentiate each height/value for a same index, you can *in addition to the bar plot* use some markers as below (Here I did not use `sns`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
# Not showing the data lists here

plt.bar(range(len(data)), data, color='b', alpha=0.3, label ='attn') #, hatch="/")
plt.bar(range(len(data2)), data2, color='g', alpha = 0.3, label ='attn_rel_pos') #, hatch="o")
plt.bar(range(len(data3)), data3, color='r',alpha = 0.3, label ='attn_comb') #, hatch="\\")
plt.plot(range(len(data)), data,'bx', alpha = 0.5)
plt.plot(range(len(data2)), data2,'go', alpha = 0.5, ms = 4)
plt.plot(range(len(data3)), data3,'r+', alpha = 0.5)
plt.grid()
plt.legend(fontsize=16)
```

**Output**

[image]

In case you want them as continuous lines, you can use the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / np.exp(x).sum(axis=0)

# Not showing the data lists here

softmax_flag = True

if softmax_flag:
    plt.plot(range(len(data)), softmax(data),'-b', alpha = 0.5, label ='attn')
    plt.plot(range(len(data2)), softmax(data2),'-g', alpha = 0.5, lw=2, label ='attn_rel_pos')
    plt.plot(range(len(data3)), softmax(data3),'-r', alpha = 0.5, lw=2, label ='attn_comb')
    ax.fill_between(range(len(data)), 0, softmax(data), color='dodgerblue', alpha = 0.4)
    ax.fill_between(range(len(data)), 0, softmax(data2), color='mediumseagreen', alpha = 0.4)
    ax.fill_between(range(len(data)), 0, softmax(data3), color='indianred', alpha = 0.4)   
else:
    plt.bar(range(len(data)), data, color='b', alpha=0.3, label ='attn') #, hatch="/")
    plt.bar(range(len(data2)), data2, color='g', alpha = 0.3, label ='attn_rel_pos') #, hatch="o")
    plt.bar(range(len(data3)), data3, color='r',alpha = 0.3, label ='attn_comb') #, hatch="\\")
    plt.plot(range(len(data)), data,'bx', alpha = 0.5)
    plt.plot(range(len(data2)), data2,'go', alpha = 0.5, ms = 4)
    plt.plot(range(len(data3)), data3,'r+', alpha = 0.5)

plt.title("Head 3")
plt.xlabel("Word Position in the Sentence")
plt.ylabel("Attention Weight")

plt.grid()
plt.legend(fontsize=16)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think the way those bars overlap is quite unclear, when they overlap I can't really see which one is the lowest contibuting one since the color kind of blends in. I need to see each data point at each index more clearly somehow, hence I thought having some sort of histogram is more illustrative.

Comment: Each bar goes up to the value in the list. So the overlap is clear since all 3 values for a given index are different. You can also additionally plot the data points at the top of the bar with three different symbols to know where the overlap bars end.

Comment: Plz check my edited answer if it is more clear/helpful

Comment: Thanks, in your second example I am not getting the bars at all, only the x, o and +. Can you, please, post the full code example? I guess I am missing something.

Comment: Did it do any help?

Comment: Yes, it works now. I would still prefer something with a line instead of bars. Would it help if the values are always higher than 0? I've edited my example.

Comment: By continuous line do you mean a curve connecting all points OR vertical thin lines instead of thick bars? For the first case, you can replace `'bx'` by `'-bx'` and so on in your three plot commands and comment out the bar plots

Comment: I mean the first case, trying that out.

Comment: I added the new plot in my answer. Check it out and let me know

Comment: This is exactly what I need, again I can't get it to work, can you provide the whole code, please?

Comment: Ok, I do, but your colors are somehow really much darker than mine. Can you post the full code just in case, please.

Comment: sorry, I've got another question. How can I increase the x labels size/bins? to show it every 5 positions instead of 10?

Comment: Just add `plt.xticks(range(0,len(data3)+1, 5))` at the end before saving/showing